# Is data returned in %jdbc paragraph available in subsequent paragraphs?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

If a paragraph returns data from the %jdbc intepreter, is that data available to following paragraphs that use other interpreters?

eg

```
 %jdbc(psql)
 select * from `table`
```

then

```
 %python
 # load / access data here
 x = ...
```

In the same way that a %spark interpreter can create a temporal table, a following paragraph can run %sql.

Comment: looks like duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968803/zeppelin-sql-reuse-data-of-query-without-another-interpreter-or-a-new-query/45046993#45046993 I answered there. You can use spark sql programmatically.

Comment: @1ambda you didnt answer at all, here it's about "reuse" not "re-execute". Looks like the answer is nop, you cannot. Maybe with https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#get-the-status-of-a-single-paragraph but it sounds hard and dirty.

Comment: It's not for re-use. It's for how to create a table and access it in a programming language (python here). Did u read the title of the question? `in subsequent paragraphs`

Comment: The duplicated question / answer was removed and is not visible anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Zeppelin has [Generic JDBC Interpreter](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/interpreter/jdbc.html) for connect to different data source with JDBC.

It lets you create a JDBC connection to any data source, by now it has been tested with:

- Postgres
- MySql
- MariaDB
- Redshift
- Apache Hive
- Apache Phoenix
- Apache Drill

According to the code in `org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql`, it only display the data.

So possible solution for getting data from a data source and use it in other interpreters could be.

- Write a function use Scala with Spark interpreter. It connect to data source and generate DataFrame based on the query result.
- Extend JDBCInterpreter, or create a new intepreter based on JDBCInterpreter which query towards the data source and generate DataFrame based on the result. This might require extend SQL syntax to add this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RockieYang - unfortunately what you've given me is something I already know. What I need to know is how to access the data returned in a %jdbc paragraph from other paragraphs.

Comment: Yes. I did not realize it when I first post the answer. I added some possible solutions I could think of.